# How to make a final global variable in Android

Tags: android, initialization, global-variables, final

I searched but didn't found an answer.
How can I make a variable final and global.
I already tried this:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    ...
}
```

But i got this error:

```
06-07 19:57:38.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13810): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.
StartActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to
Activities before onCreate()
```

I don't know how to avoid this error, because when I tried this:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private final Dialog dialog;
    ...
}
```

and initialize the variable in the onCreate() method, I get this error in Eclipse:

```
The blank final field dialog may not have been initialized.
```

Comment: why do you need it to be final. remove the final modifier. declare it as a instance variable

Comment: i need the variable to be final, because i use it in an onClick method:`dialog.dismiss`

Comment: still there is no need for the final modifier. try the below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the final modifier

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

private Dialog dialog; // declare it as a instance variable

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
      dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
      // initialize dialog
}
```

Now you can use the `dialog` in `onClick`.

Also note `this` refers to Activity Context and context is available once activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to instantiate in `onCreate`? Instantiate it on `onClick`.

Comment: if i instantiate in onClick i get the error: `The blank final field dialog may not have been initialized.`

Comment: You don't need to have it as a final field anymore, make it a local variable.

Comment: But i also use the same dialog in another function to get views `dialog.findViewById(...)`

Comment: Then I would go with Raghunandan's answer -- did you try it?